# AngularJS ng-repeat — declarative filters vs. imperative filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I should use declarative style and when imperative in Angular filters?

For example, I want to **orderBy** and **limitTo** some array of objects in **ng-repeat**. In which cases it is better to use declarative inline filters right in the HTML code:

```
var items = [
    {id:123, date:1412631216000},
    {id:328, date:1412631217000},

    … // 50 more tiny objects

    {id:553, date:1412631398000}
];

$scope.limit = 5;
$scope.items = items; // there will be 53 items, but I need only 5 of them to display on a page

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'date':true | limitTo:limit">
        …
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in which cases it is worth to filter and limit an array manually?

```
// I usually have Lo-Dash.js or Underscore.js in all my projects

var limit = 5;

var items = [
    {id:123, date:1412631843000},
    {id:328, date:1412631217000},

    … // 50 more tiny objects

    {id:553, date:1412631398000}
];

items = _.sortBy(items, 'date');

items.reverse();

items = items.slice(0, limit);

$scope.items = items; // there will be exactly what I need for output — 5 items

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        …
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: in choosing your filters, you have to consider: 1) how lazy you are currently. 
- if you wanted something that existed, and too lazy to write javascript. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With AngularJs you can use both ways:

1. **Use filters**
   If you have your ***ng-repeat*** on the template you for sure need to use declarative filters. It's really awesome feature designed in this framework. 
   The only drawback is that your dataset be pulled through all the filters you define ***on each $digest() cycle***. It may cause some performance issues. But anyway in most cases it's a beautiful tool that should be used.
2. **Use custom filtering**
   Sometimes you need to preprocess you data in your model. For example when you received very long array and you don't want to make Angular default filters to process 1 000 000 entries. In this case you can use some kind of data cursor that sorts data in memory in fast way and then pass data to Angular **$scope <-> View system.**